# Woocomerce pulling wrong time from server -5 hrs difference

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, date-time

I wonder could anyone help me with the time zones.
In my wordpress i have the time zone set for New York, When i make a booking on my wordpress the booking is added to woocommerce cart and the time is totally changed by 5 hours differnece.
I think i have found the correct file to edit in woocommerce wc-formatting-functions.php

```
/**
 * Convert mysql datetime to PHP timestamp, forcing UTC. Wrapper for strtotime.
 *
 * Based on wcs_strtotime_dark_knight() from WC Subscriptions by Prospress.
 *
 * @since  3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $time_string
 * @param int|null $from_timestamp
 *
 * @return int
 */
function wc_string_to_timestamp( $time_string, $from_timestamp = null ) {
    $original_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );

    if ( null === $from_timestamp ) {
        $next_timestamp = strtotime( $time_string );
    } else {
        $next_timestamp = strtotime( $time_string, $from_timestamp );
    }

    date_default_timezone_set( $original_timezone );
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    return $next_timestamp;
}
```

or maybe this part

```
function wc_timezone_string() {

    // if site timezone string exists, return it
    if ( $timezone = get_option( 'timezone_string' ) ) {
        return $timezone;
    }

    // get UTC offset, if it isn't set then return UTC
    if ( 0 === ( $utc_offset = intval( get_option( 'gmt_offset', 0 ) ) ) ) {
        return 'UTC';
    }

    // adjust UTC offset from hours to seconds
    $utc_offset *= 3600;

    // attempt to guess the timezone string from the UTC offset
    if ( $timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr( '', $utc_offset ) ) {
        return $timezone;
    }

    // last try, guess timezone string manually
    foreach ( timezone_abbreviations_list() as $abbr ) {
        foreach ( $abbr as $city ) {
            if ( (bool) date( 'I' ) === (bool) $city['dst'] && $city['timezone_id'] && intval( $city['offset'] ) === $utc_offset ) {
                return $city['timezone_id'];
            }
        }
    }

    // fallback to UTC
    return 'UTC';
}
```

Comment: Internally, WordPress timestamp are stored in UTC format. What is the code you use to read the date ?

Comment: i have just posted the code that woocommerce uses for the date. I am using two plugins Bookly which pulls the time from the wordpress time zone and wocommerce which seems to pull the time from the server and not the wordpress time zone

Answer (score 1):

For the date Woocommerce CODE

```
function wc_string_to_datetime( $time_string ) {
    // Strings are defined in local WP timezone. Convert to UTC.
    if ( 1 === preg_match( '/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(Z|((-|\+)\d{2}:\d{2}))$/', $time_string, $date_bits ) ) {
        $offset    = ! empty( $date_bits[7] ) ? iso8601_timezone_to_offset( $date_bits[7] ) : wc_timezone_offset();
        $timestamp = gmmktime( $date_bits[4], $date_bits[5], $date_bits[6], $date_bits[2], $date_bits[3], $date_bits[1] ) - $offset;
    } else {
        $timestamp = wc_string_to_timestamp( get_gmt_from_date( gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', wc_string_to_timestamp( $time_string ) ) ) );
    }
    $datetime  = new WC_DateTime( "@{$timestamp}", new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );

    // Set local timezone or offset.
    if ( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) ) {
        $datetime->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( wc_timezone_string() ) );
    } else {
        $datetime->set_utc_offset( wc_timezone_offset() );
    }

    return $datetime;
}
```